# Key not valid for use in specific state:Cryptographic Encryption and Decryption exception

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, windows-server-2008-r2

My application has encryption and decryption mechanism on sensitive data. We migrated to new server which is windows server 2008 R2 and 64-bit OS but the old server is 32-bit OS Windows server 2003.
We are facing issues with the encryption 
error prone area in the code.

And I want to know what kind of user privileges required and need to know any changes required for 64-bit OS

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Key not valid for use in specified state.\r\n"
  Source="mscorlib[ERROR CODE:934e01d0-e812-4927-8c32-dd812373a22f]"
  StackTrace:
       at AIG_OQS.PolicySections.IDMain.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\AOL\ChartisOnLine\ChartisOnLine\AIG On Line\ChartisOnLine\ChartisOnLine\ChartisOnLine\APP_COL_FrontEnd\PolicyGeneral\IDMain.aspx.cs:line 197
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Code snippet is given below:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;

_encryptRSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
_encryptRSA.ImportParameters(_encryptRSA.ExportParameters(false));

_decryptRSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
_decryptRSA.ImportParameters(_decryptRSA.ExportParameters(true)); // <- Exception
```

Comment: Please anybody can help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Do your new server have permissions assigned on it's KeyStores?

Comment: Yes it is a permission issue i have resolved it. Thanks Bardo

Comment: this is the premission issue . Thanks Bardo